# Unable to start most programs & services on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, avast

Since yesterday I am facing an issue on my computer, that occured after I needed to force reboot because of a graphic card crash.

When starting up my session, the sound service is not started, and my antivirus (Avast) is not starting as well. I am not able to start most of the programs (exe files, msi installations, and so on). Even some Windows 10 native programs (such as Add / Remove a program) won't show up. Some basic programs and others such as Chrome (?) are working fine.

When I try to start the Audio service manually, I get the message "Access denied". Moreover there are a lot of events in the Windows event logger that show up "Access denied".

I already tried some solutions found on the Internet:

- Restore exe files associations -> everything is correctly set up
- Running sfc /scannow -> no error message
- Checking owner of C: drive -> Adminstrators group is set with "Full control" on it
- Trying to register some missing DLL files -> the registration end point is not found on those DLLs
- Trying to safe boot -> same behavior occurs
- Trying to create a new user account as Admin - I also activated the Administrator account to check- -> same behavior in the new session

I also tried to rollback to a restoration point, however it fails with error 0x80070005: on the Internet it is said that I have to disable / uninstall Avast first. But the problem is that I cannot run anything that could be able to do that: they won't start because of the first issue.

Some more details about my configuration:

- 500 GB SSD with about 50% of free space
- 16 GB RAM
- Windows 10 Pro

Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It crashed hard and screwed the windows permissions, I would back up personal files and reinstall Windows 10 clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you have not yet done so, make a disk image in case something goes wrong with repairs. This can be run from external media using a third-party backup program, such as free [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) which can create [rescue media](https://kb.macrium.com/knowledgebasearticle50210.aspx) using WinPE.

Then, in SAFE mode, [try using *DISM* to repair system files](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image):

- Open a CMD prompt as Administrator: press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and click `Yes` in the UAC dialog.
- Type (or copy & paste) `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` in the CMD window. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait some minutes for the process to finish.
- If corruption was detected, enter `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>... and wait even longer for repairs to complete.
- After *DISM* finishes, repeat `SFC /scannow`.

If that does not resolve the issue, you can [download the latest Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and [perform repair](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085), or even a complete reinstallation.

It is possible to use *DISM* to repair using the file *boot.wim* in the Windows.iso\sources\ folder, but my experience has been that running the ISO in repair mode has a better chance of success.

Comment: The DISM did not change the SFC result, even in safe mode. However, I booted with the ISO and I was able to rollback to a restoration point from outside Windows. Everything is back now ;) Thanks!

Comment: Glad the advice helped! Using the Windows ISO has also allowed me to update laptops that repeatedly failed to update online.